# Two PrintWriter objects printing only once

Tags: java, printwriter

I have the following code snippet. The code looks fine, however it fails to print `Bye` on the screen.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PrintWriterTwice {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintWriter first = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    first.print("Hello");
    first.flush();
    first.close();

    PrintWriter second = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    second.print("Bye");
    second.flush();
    second.close();
  }
}
```

Here's the output of the program:

> Hello

May I know why do I get this behaviour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `close()` on a `PrintWriter` closes the underlying `OutputStream` (in this case `System.out`); so you get no further output. Remove the `close()` - or move it to after your `second` writes.

```
PrintWriter first = new PrintWriter(System.out);
first.print("Hello");
first.flush();

PrintWriter second = new PrintWriter(System.out);
second.print("Bye");
second.flush();
first.close();
second.close();
```

Comment: It worked. I tried `System.out.close()`, and I could reproduce the same behavior. Thanks a lot :)